# AngularFire2: Access User Profile

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am going round in circles and hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

**Business Problem**
I have an AngularFire2 App that I want to perform the following steps:

1. User Registers as a user in Firebase
2. User then fills out a registration form with additional information (Customer or Organisation they work for).  Then they click on save
3. New Customer is created
4. User Profile is created with the customer key of the customer created in step 3

   5. User is redirected to customer list page and it only displays any customers with the customer id on the logged in users profile

I have all the steps working but what I cannot seem to work out is how to get the user profile information before triggering the call for Get All Customers on the Customer Service.

Ideally what I would like to do is inject the User Service into the Customer Service to identify who the current user is and what their customer id is, so i can pass that as an argument into the Get All Customers Function.

I can easily call into the AuthService and subscribe to the uid on the firebase authstate, but i cannot work out how to get from there to look up the user profile.

Code

**AuthService**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods, FirebaseAuthState, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { UserModel } from '../../user/models/user.model';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  user: UserModel;
  userProfile: any;
  userId: string;
  usersRef: string = '/users/';

  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private router: Router) {

    this.af.auth.subscribe(authState => {
      this.user = authState;
      console.log('authService Constructor: ', this.user)
    });
  }

  register(email?: string, password?: string) {
    this.af.auth.createUser({ email, password })
      .then(response => this.router.navigate(['/user/add/']))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  isAuth(): UserModel {
    return this.user;
  }
}
```

**User Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';

import { AuthService } from '../../auth/services/auth.service';
import { FirebaseService } from '../../core/services/firebase.service';
import { CustomerService } from '../../customer/services/customer.service';

import { UserModel } from '../models/user.model';
import { CustomerModel } from '../../customer/models/customer.model';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  usersRef: string = '/users/';
  user: UserModel;
  customer: CustomerModel = new CustomerModel(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
  customerKey: string;
  userId: string;

  constructor(
    private af: AngularFire,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private customerService: CustomerService,
    private firebaseService: FirebaseService,
    private router: Router) {


  }

  getAllUsers(): FirebaseListObservable<UserModel[]> {
    return this.af.database.list(this.usersRef);
  }

  getUser(){
    return this.af.database.list(this.usersRef, {
      query: {
        orderByKey: true,
        equalTo: this.userId
      }
    })
  }

  addUser(user: any) {

    this.createNewCustomer(user.organisation);

    this.createUser(user);

    this.saveUser();

  }

  createUser(user: UserModel) {
    this.user = user;
    this.user.createdDate = user.createdDate = Date.now();
    this.user.customerId = this.customerKey;
  }

  saveUser() {
    this.af.database.list(this.usersRef).push(this.user)
      .then(response => {
        this.redirectToCustomerList();
      });
  }

  createNewCustomer(organisation: string) {
    this.customerKey = this.firebaseService.createUniqueKey('customers');
    this.customer.organisation = organisation;
    this.customerService.addCustomer(this.customer, this.customerKey);
  }

  redirectToCustomerList() {

    this.router.navigate(['/customer/list']);
  }

}
```

**Customer Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';

import { CustomerModel } from '../models/customer.model';

@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {

  customersRef: string = '/customers/';
  customer: CustomerModel;
  userId: string;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {

  }

  getAllCustomers(): FirebaseListObservable<CustomerModel[]> {

    return this.af.database.list(this.customersRef, {
      query: {
        orderByKey: true,
        equalTo: this.userId
      }
    })
  }

  getCustomer(id: string): FirebaseObjectObservable<any> {
    return this.af.database.object(this.customersRef + id);
  }

  addCustomer(customer: CustomerModel, customerKey?: string): any {
    customer.createdDate = Date.now();
    if (customerKey) {
      this.af.database.object(this.customersRef + customerKey).set(customer);
    } else {
      this.af.database.list(this.customersRef).push(customer);
    }
    return customerKey;
  }

  updateCustomer(customerIndex: string, customer: CustomerModel) {
    this.af.database.object(this.customersRef).update(customer);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```ts
customerForCurrentUser$ = this.af.auth
  .map(user => user.$key)
  .switchMap(key => this.customerService.getCustomer(key))
```

Comment: I just get an error saying switchMap is not a function TypeError: this.af.auth.map(...).switchMap is not a function

Comment: You probably forgot to import it - `import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'`

Comment: Correct :-).  I am not familiar with switch map, how do i then pull out the actual customerKey from this.  I am getting an Anonymous Subject back

Comment: `customerForCurrentUser$` is a cold observable, subscribe to it, either with `subscribe()` in your code, or `async` pipe in template